# Limit the size of files that enter the recycle bin in win7

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk-space, recycle-bin

Is there a way to limit the size of files that can enter the recycle bin?
For example, let's say I want only files that are smaller than 500MB to enter the recycle bin. How can I do it?

(I delete a lot of movies and tv episodes, and they fill up my bin and take up space for documents and things that I'm much more likely to want to recover.)

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You can however use <shift><del> on your movies to bypass the recycle bin completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do that easily in Windows 7 but there are two other things you can do that might help you.

#### Delete large files directly

When you want to delete a movie or TV episode, select it in Explorer and hit `Shift + Delete`, confirm when the dialog pops up, and the file will skip the recycle bin and be permanently deleted.

#### Limit the size of the recycle bin

You can limit the size of the recycle bin by right-clicking the icon and going to Properties -> General. Then you can set the amount of space in megabytes that the recycle bin takes up on each of your mounted drives. When the bin hits the limit it will automatically delete old files to "make room" for the newer files you delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your view of (default) windows file explorer to **`detailed`** and then there should be a column named `size` click it to sort all files acc. to size and now you may drag and select out of thousands of files easily which are smaller than 500MB. After that you can use `Shift`+`del` to bypass recycle bin and directly free your disk from selected files.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to set a per-file size limit for the Recycle Bin. If you really want to, though, you can ban certain folders' contents from the Bin. First, we need enable folder redirection for the target folder. Open the Registry Editor (`regedit`) and navigate here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

This procedure will only work on the folders listed there. Let's say you want to affect your Videos folder. Folder redirection only "counts" for purposes of Recycle Bin customization if it goes to a UNC path. Create a file share on your personal Videos folder accessible only to you. Make sure your account has Full Control on the share. If you named the share `Videos`, you would set the `My Video` Registry entry to `\\localhost\Videos`. This won't change where your videos are stored, but it will make Windows think redirection is in place.

Now the Videos folder is a candidate for Recycle Bin configuration. Navigate in the Registry Editor to here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\BitBucket
```

Create a new key called `KnownFolder` inside `BitBucket`. Now you need to choose which folder you want to control. [Here's the list of known locations and their IDs.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882665(v=vs.110).aspx) Grab the GUID, enclose it in curly braces, and create a new key with that name under `KnownFolder`. For example, this is the one for Videos: `{18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}`.

Under that key, create a DWORD value called `MaxCapacity` and give it any value larger than zero. Then create another DWORD called `NukeOnDelete` and set it to 1; this makes deleted items be torched immediately.

If you'd like to change the behavior of other folders, just redirect them similarly and add another subkey of `KnownFolder` with those values.

Confirmed working on Windows 7 Home. I'm not sure if you actually want to use this, though, since it's a horrible hack. It's almost certainly better to just use Shift+Delete on files you want to completely remove (as suggested by DavidPostill in the comments).

Source for the Registry tweaks: [Managing the Recycle bin with Redirected Folders with Vista or Windows 7](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/07/16/managing-the-recycle-bin-with-redirected-folders-with-vista-or-windows-7/), [Registry Settings for Folder Redirection in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/242557)